# Attiny85 crashes when I run a motor through an L293D

Tags: arduino, power-supply, motor, attiny85, l293d

I'm trying to run a motor through an L293D turned on and off by an Attiny85. The Attiny85 has the micronucleus bootloader on it, which is why pin 3 is connected to a pull up resistor.

On the Attiny is a program that toggles PB0 on and off every second. I've attached an LED indicator on it, and while the motor is not connected to 1Y, it runs fine. It also works fine if I put an LED between 1Y and ground. But when I put a small motor between 1Y and ground, LED1 flashes briefly and then the Attiny resets.

Basically, how do I get it to not crash when running a motor through it?

[image: Motor on L293D]
I also tried the following, putting the motor directly on the power supply, doing so prevents the Attiny from starting at all.

[image: Motor on power supply]
Specs:

- 5V wall power supply with up to 3000mA output.
- Motor pulls around 300 mA while active.
- Also tried powering it through my computer's USB and got the same results.

What I've tried:

- Replacing C2 with a 1000uF capacitor. That allowed me to plug the motor directly to the power supply with the Attiny85 running.
- Putting the 1000uF capacitor between 1Y and gnd. No change.

**Update 1:**

The reason I was using L293D is because I didn't have any viable diodes at hand while testing. The only ones I had were too big to put on my breadboard. Connected it through alligator clips for now, and made the following changes, and that seems to be working quite well for now:

[image]

Comment: You have no decoupling capacitors.

Comment: @Toor where do I put those?

Comment: Rule of thumb is 0.1uF ceramic across every pair of power pins for every IC as close as possible to the IC. You also have no flyback diodes.

Comment: On top of what @Toor said, your layout matters in this regard. Please show your layout.

Comment: @Toor, L293D has built in flyback diodes. I'll add some capacitors near the power pins and see what happens.

Comment: @Toor, worked perfectly, feel free to put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Your ultimate problem here is that your power supply is underspecified for the load.  However, using the L293 the way you are makes no sense - first, it's a horribly lossy device, and a second, you don't need that to achieve the unidirectional control you have wired for.  What you want is a good power supply, and a good low threshold N-FET wired as a low side switch.

Comment: It may be a bit cheeky but you can add a diode between your 5V power rail and the AtTiny.  Than add your decoupling caps after the diode.  So when the supply dips the diode prevents the capacitors from discharging into the motor. The idea is the Capacitors power the AtTiny during the motor's start up. Of course Chris Stratton is correct that the best answer is better rated supply and switching to a low side mosfet.  Keep tinkering, brown-outs highlight many important concepts in electronics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no decoupling capacitors.

You need decoupling capacitors because whenever the ICs switch they will try to draw a surge of current. The power supply can't respond fast enough and even if it does, the current surge will produce a voltage drop through the parasitic inductance of the wires and traces. Either scenario will cause a brownout.

The rule of thumb is to place 0.1uF ceramic capacitors across every pair of power pins as close to the IC as possible.

Comment: No.  While that is a good idea as a general principle, it is *not* the issue here.  The issue is that the motor is overloading the power supply, whatever that is.  If this "solves" the problem it's luck, not sound engineering.

Comment: Motors draw much more than steady state when starting.  Again, bypass capacitors are a good idea.  But they are not a sound solution to this problem.

Comment: OP has stated that they already added 1000uF caps prior to adding this post which should have alleviated current surge issues from the motor.

Comment: Read their actual statement and you'll see that they put that cap in an utterly useless place.

Comment: Hah, right you are. That cap should be going across the power rails. A decoupling cap just for the motor, so to speak. I do question the reasoning that the supply is undersized if adding a capacitor satisfies the surge requirements. It can't be expected to be able to straight up supply the surge current all the time.

Comment: What happens when the load on the motor changes?  When whatever it spins gets mechanically stuck?

Comment: Motor load changes are really up to the application so it's an unknown right now so it's premature to say it's undersized. If anything the driver is undersized for what the supply can provide but that capacity might not be needed for the application. And any stalled motor is going to drag down a supply of any reasonable size so that's a moot example.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Where do I put the 1000uF capacitor? When I tested, I put it across V and GND of the power supply where it entered the circuit.

Comment: I don't have any extremely precise equipment, but checking max current with a multimeter says 0.25A, and my power supply is rated for 3A.

Comment: The 1000uF is another decoupling capacitor except it is for your motor. So it goes straight across your power rails. Larger capacitors are for lower frequencies where distance does not matter as much so it doesn't have to be as close as possible to your motor. What @ChrisStratton is talking about is how motors pull a current at least several times higher than the maximum current on startup since they are basically stalled on startup. This is too short and fast to see with a multimeter. You need a scope to see it.

Comment: @Toor Ok yeah that's what I did in the first example, I see the I put the wrong value on it though. Should have been 1000uF. But I'm guessing I need both across the rails and one specifically for the microcontroller.

Comment: As I just mentioned larger capacitors don't work at higher frequencies where the effect of parasitic inductances are most prominent. This inductance is why you have to place the smaller capacitors close to the chips. In other words, with larger capacitors, you don't need to worry about as much with physical placement and closeness. So just one 1000uF for everything should be enough.